# Import some android classes in a java project (eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class, import

I need to have access to some android classes in a non-android project (just java project) in Eclipse.

What I actually need to do:

```
Class c = Class.forName("android.widget.Button");
```

Obviously I get a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.widget.Button

Can I do what I want to do?

Comment: You have to add whole **android.jar** to do this.. And still can't be sure if it works..

Comment: The **android.jar** you will add also depends on the Android API level you want the *Button* class from.

Comment: How can I add android.jar? I tried with Configure Build Path->Add Library->Android Classpath Container but I obtain "Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one."
If I create on project.properties file it still doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

do not ad Android Classpath Container in eclipse , instead add individual android.jar..its recommended to add the highest android version and than create a local.properties file to store the location for your build script.

Comment: where i can find the android.jar i have to add to my project?